# Sorting an XML file through XSL

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an XML file that I want to sort by an attribute. The file is structured as shown below:

```
<wb xmlns:cf="http://www.macromedia.com/2004/cfform">

    <a:form name="chart">  

        <a:input FIELDNUMBER="09" INDEX="2" LEFT="200" />
        <a:input FIELDNUMBER="08" INDEX="3" LEFT="200" />

        <a:fieldset FIELD="a" FIELDNAME="FieldSet1">                              
            <a:input FIELDNUMBER="02" INDEX="4" LEFT="200" />
            <a:select1  FIELDNUMBER="01" />
        </a:fieldset>

        <a:fieldset FIELD="b" FIELDNAME="FieldSet1">                              
            <a:input FIELDNUMBER="04" INDEX="7" LEFT="200" />
            <a:select1  FIELDNUMBER="03" />
            <a:fieldset FIELD="c" FIELDNAME="FieldSet1">                              
                <a:input FIELDNUMBER="06" INDEX="8" LEFT="200" />
                <a:input FIELDNUMBER="05" INDEX="6" LEFT="200" />
            </a:fieldset>
       </a:fieldset>

    </a:form>

</wb>
```

I would like to sort the above XML all throughout by @fieldnumber, but at the same I want to keep the same structure of the XML. I have managed to sort other XML file but they did not have such nesting levels. Is this possible with XSL alone and if so how can this be done?

The output should be as follows:

```
<wb xmlns:cf="http://www.macromedia.com/2004/cfform">

    <a:form name="chart">  

        <a:input FIELDNUMBER="08" INDEX="3" LEFT="200" />
        <a:input FIELDNUMBER="09" INDEX="2" LEFT="200" />

        <a:fieldset FIELD="a" FIELDNAME="FieldSet1">                              
            <a:select1  FIELDNUMBER="01" />
            <a:input FIELDNUMBER="02" INDEX="4" LEFT="200" />
        </a:fieldset>

        <a:fieldset FIELD="b" FIELDNAME="FieldSet1">                              
            <a:select1  FIELDNUMBER="03" />
            <a:input FIELDNUMBER="04" INDEX="7" LEFT="200" />
            <a:fieldset FIELD="c" FIELDNAME="FieldSet1">                              
                <a:input FIELDNUMBER="05" INDEX="6" LEFT="200" />
                <a:input FIELDNUMBER="06" INDEX="8" LEFT="200" />
            </a:fieldset>
       </a:fieldset>

    </a:form>

</wb>
```

As another example, should the FIELDNUMBER 04 be changed to a value greater than 7 such as 10 (let's assume 10 in this example) then the output of the fieldset with FIELD value b becomes:

```
        <a:fieldset FIELD="b" FIELDNAME="FieldSet1">                              
            <a:select1  FIELDNUMBER="03" />
            <a:fieldset FIELD="c" FIELDNAME="FieldSet1">                              
                <a:input FIELDNUMBER="05" INDEX="6" LEFT="200" />
                <a:input FIELDNUMBER="06" INDEX="8" LEFT="200" />
            </a:fieldset>
            <a:input FIELDNUMBER="10" INDEX="7" LEFT="200" />
       </a:fieldset>
```

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "keep the same structure of the XML" in this context.  Show what the output from sorting the sample input would look like.

Comment: Done. 

Jim, basically what I mean is that if the XML contains around 20 lines then the sorted output would have the same amount of lines. This means that the sorting function will simply transpose the lines according to fieldnumber but at the same time the same nesting and the equal amount of levels is preserved. What makes sorting a bit difficult is that there are/could be nested elements inside the a:fieldset which I want to sort as well by fieldnumber.

Comment: That's still not quite enough info.  If you change field number 04 so it was FIELDNUMBER="10", would it remain where it is or sort behind the fieldset containing 05 and 06?

Comment: Good question! It would have to go after the element 06! So with the output with FIELDNUMBER 04 changed to 10 the bottom section becomes:

        <a:fieldset FIELD="b" FIELDNAME="FieldSet1">                              
            <a:select1  FIELDNUMBER="03" />
            <a:fieldset FIELD="c" FIELDNAME="FieldSet1">                              
                <a:input FIELDNUMBER="05" INDEX="6" LEFT="200" />
                <a:input FIELDNUMBER="06" INDEX="8" LEFT="200" />
            </a:fieldset>
            <a:input FIELDNUMBER="10" INDEX="7" LEFT="200" />
       </a:fieldset>

Comment: OK, that's inconsistent with the sorting of 08 and 09 before 01 and 02.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Despite the inconsistency pointed to by Jim Garrison, I tried to come up with something that matches your description:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
      <xsl:for-each select="*">
        <xsl:sort select="@FIELDNUMBER|.//@FIELDNUMBER"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="." />
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The sort works first on the element's FIELDNUMBER attribute, or on the first FIELDNUMBER attribute it finds on the element's children if the element doesn't have one itself. Here's the output (xmlns:a was added to the source document, so it got carried to the output):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<wb xmlns:cf="http://www.macromedia.com/2004/cfform" xmlns:a="urn:dummy">
  <a:form name="chart">
    <a:fieldset FIELD="a" FIELDNAME="FieldSet1">
      <a:select1 FIELDNUMBER="01" />
      <a:input FIELDNUMBER="02" INDEX="4" LEFT="200" />
    </a:fieldset>
    <a:fieldset FIELD="b" FIELDNAME="FieldSet1">
      <a:select1 FIELDNUMBER="03" />
      <a:input FIELDNUMBER="04" INDEX="7" LEFT="200" />
      <a:fieldset FIELD="c" FIELDNAME="FieldSet1">
        <a:input FIELDNUMBER="05" INDEX="6" LEFT="200" />
        <a:input FIELDNUMBER="06" INDEX="8" LEFT="200" />
      </a:fieldset>
    </a:fieldset>
    <a:input FIELDNUMBER="08" INDEX="3" LEFT="200" />
    <a:input FIELDNUMBER="09" INDEX="2" LEFT="200" />
  </a:form>
</wb>
```

Comment: Francis, that is just excellent! Not only you managed to understand my query but you also managed to give me an output that does exactly what I expected!