# PHP sorting an XML structure

Tags: php, arrays, xml, sorting, object

,Hi, all!

I have an XML structure that I am trying to sort by a subfield and which I then will want to style.  I think that I want to ask about sorting an object, but since that isn't really the goal I'm trying to work in terms of the deliverable :-)

The XML looks much like

```
<messages>
  <message>
    <headers>
      <From>person</From>
      <Date>2014-10-09 19:46:37</Date>
      ...
      <Message-Id>long_id_string@server.dom.ain</Message-Id>
    </headers>
    <attachments>
      <attachment mimetype="image/jpeg" name="att1.jpg" output="/path/to/image"/>
      <attachment mimetype="text/plain" name="file.txt" output="/path/to/file"/>
    </attachments>
    <body>
      Message body here.  It might
      wrap, or it might not.
    </body>
  </message>
  <message>
    <headers>
      <From>person</From>
      <Date>2016-01-01 00:00:00</Date>
      ...
      <Message-Id>other_message_string@server.dom.ain</Message-Id>
    </headers>
    <attachments/>
    <body>
      A simple message
    </body>
  </message>
  <message>
    <headers>
      <From>HTML email sender</From>
      <Date>2015-06-06 01:23:45</Date>
      ...
      <Message-Id>horrible_idea@html.mail.ser.ver</Message-Id>
    </headers>
    <attachments/>
    <body>
      <div dir="ltr"><div class="gmail_default" style="font-size:small;color:#073763">Good afternoon David &amp; Laura!</div><div class=...
    </body>
  </message>
</messages>
```

(although that's very abbreviated, of course, and prettier), and I want to sort on the message->headers->Date field.

I've grabbed some code from here and there, and I'm able to suck the structure into an array with xml2array and XMLtoArray functions I've lifted to get me started (but no word yet on spitting back out XML when I'm done; I haven't gotten that far).  They aren't as pretty as a SimpleXMLElement

```
$msgobj = new SimpleXMLElement($msgxml)
```

structure, though, which then leads me back to trying to sort an object.  All of the googling I've done covers how to sort an **array of objects** rather than a **single** complex object.  I did see [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2907572/sorting-an-xml-file-through-xsl) to XSLT magically sorting, but I'm totally lost there (what processes it? where does the sorted content go? ...).

I eventually want to spit the XML back out -- with the same structure and all of the same fields per message -- in order by date, and I hope to apply some styling to the headers and bodies for the next step.  Given that, 1) what's the simplest & best structure for the job and 2) the right way to a rusty PHP hacker to get started?

TIA & HANW

:-D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, consider [XSLT](https://www.w3.org/Style/XSL/), the special-purpose, declarative language (same type as SQL), designed to transform XML files such as sorting. Like PHP can run SQL (or rather send SQL calls to a database engine via an API e.g., PDO/mysqli), PHP can send an XSLT 1.0 script to an XSLT processor (libxslt) with its built-in [php-xsl](http://php.net/manual/en/book.xsl.php) class.

**XSLT** *(save below as .xsl script or string variable which is a well-formed .xml file)*

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="/messages">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="message">
        <xsl:sort select="headers/Date"/>
      </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="message">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**PHP** *(run below loading input xml and xsl, be sure to have php-xsl extension enabled in .ini file)*

```
// LOAD XML AND XSL
$xml = new DOMDocument();
$xml->load('Input.xml');       // OR $xml->loadXML($xmlstring);

$xsl = new DOMDocument;
$xsl->load('XSLTScript.xsl');  // OR $xsl->loadXML($xslstring);

// INITIALIZE TRANSFORMER
$proc = new XSLTProcessor;
$proc->importStyleSheet($xsl); 

// RUN TRANSFORMATION
$newXML = $proc->transformToXML($xml);

// ECHO STRING OUTPUT
echo $newXML;

// SAVE OUTPUT TO FILE
file_put_contents('Output.xml', $newXML);
```

**Output** *(abbreviated `<div...` was removed for well-formed XML)*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<messages>
  <message>
    <headers>
      <From>person</From>
      <Date>2014-10-09 19:46:37</Date>
      <Message-Id>long_id_string@server.dom.ain</Message-Id>
    </headers>
    <attachments>
      <attachment mimetype="image/jpeg" name="att1.jpg" output="/path/to/image" />
      <attachment mimetype="text/plain" name="file.txt" output="/path/to/file" />
    </attachments>
    <body>
      Message body here.  It might
      wrap, or it might not.
    </body>
  </message>
  <message>
    <headers>
      <From>HTML email sender</From>
      <Date>2015-06-06 01:23:45</Date>
      <Message-Id>horrible_idea@html.mail.ser.ver</Message-Id>
    </headers>
    <attachments />
    <body>
      <div dir="ltr">
        <div class="gmail_default" style="font-size:small;color:#073763">Good afternoon David &amp; Laura!</div>
      </div>
    </body>
  </message>
  <message>
    <headers>
      <From>person</From>
      <Date>2016-01-01 00:00:00</Date>
      <Message-Id>other_message_string@server.dom.ain</Message-Id>
    </headers>
    <attachments />
    <body>
      A simple message
    </body>
  </message>
</messages>
```

Comment: holy smokes! that looks awesome. i'm off to start trying this on my own now. thanks!!! and stay tuned.

Comment: YES!  This is perfect; I played around and was able to sort in a few different ways; woo hoo.  Thanks again!  I have to go back and rework some processing in my IMAP pull script (to flatten HTML body content to plain text) and then I'll get back to learning about applying styling through XSLT and iterating through the object.  More learning fun ahead :-)

Comment: Excellent to hear! Indeed, you can extend the styling with XSLT as it can transform XML to other XML, HTML, even text (CSV)! Happy coding. Glad I could help.